# Kconfig and LKM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kbuild

I'm working with LKM outside the kernel tree and I want to use some compiling options for my module like MYLKM_CONFIG_{something}. I know that this can be done using the C preprocessing (#define // #ifdef // #endif). But I want to know is it possible to use Kbuild (Kconfig files or something related) for that purposes?..

And one more question. Is it possible to `make menuconfig` for only my module, not for the whole kernel tree?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a good idea to post the second question as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the recommanded method for building drivers outside of the tree (see ldd Chapter 2), the command should look like this:

```
$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

The effect of this command is two:

1. the -C option changes the current directory to the `$(KERNELDIR)` where it finds the main kernel Makefile
2. the -M option makes the makefile go back your current module dev directory `$(PWD)`, where it tries to build the modules target

So if you copy your .config from `$(KERNELDIR)` to `$(PWD)`, it should be parsed by the Makefile and you should have all your CONFIG_LKM_* #defines available (not tested though, but it sounds logical).

For the `make menconfig` question, with regards to the above explanation, it may work if you add some KConfig files in your `$(PWD)` directory.

Comment: Well, thanks for reply but it's not exactly what I want to know. The question is about how to use `.config`-like project file in addition to kernel's one.

Comment: I don't think the kernel supports two `.config` files. You would have to copy one from a kernel dir to your module dir and add some #defines in it.